# Create a dynamic course map on a jsp site

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, graphics

I have to do this for an assignment.

Requirements are:
1. This is a student course information page for all four years
2. All courses will be displayed column wise for each year
3. Each course/unit should display a link to its subordinate course or every time a student clicks on a course it should display a link to its consecutive next course
4. What it means is each course should display a link to its prerequisite course
5. If there is no prereq, then no link
6. This all need to be done dynamically

I have a jsp/html site where i will include this page. Could you please suggest how do i go about doing this. E.g: what language i can use to draw arrow link or mapping in a jsp site.

Your help is much appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Dynamic Form</TITLE></HEAD>
 2: <BODY>
 3: <B>Form</B>
 4: <FORM ACTION=dynamicForm.jsp METHOD=POST>
 5: <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
 6: <%  String[] textFields = {"FirstName","LastName","Address","City","Zip"};
 7:     for(int j=0; j<textFields.length; j++){     %>
 8:     <TR>    <TD> <%=textFields[j]%>:                       </TD>
 9:             <TD> <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=<%=textFields[j]%>> </TD>
10:     </TR>
11: <%  }   %>
12:     <TR>    <TD> State  </TD>
13:             <TD> <SELECT NAME=State>
14: <%  String[] states = {"AZ", "CA", "NM", "MA", "ME", "MD", "..."};
15:     for(int s=0; s<states.length; s++) {    %>
16:                     <OPTION><%=states[s]%></OPTION>
17: <%  }   %>
18:                  </SELECT></TD>
19:     </TR>
20:     <TR>    <TD> Card Number  </TD>
21:             <TD> <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=cNumber></TD>
22:     </TR>
23:     <TR>    <TD> Card Type  </TD>
24:             <TD> <SELECT NAME=CardType>
25: <%  String[] cTypes = {"Amex", "Visa", "Master Card", "Discovery", "..."};
26:     for(int t=0; t<cTypes.length; t++) {    %>
27:                     <OPTION><%=cTypes[t]%></OPTION>
28: <%  }   %>
29:                  </SELECT></TD>
30:     </TR>
31:     <TR>    <TD> Expiration Date (MM/DD/YYYY) </TD>
32: <TD> <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=cMonth SIZE=2><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=cDay SIZE=2>
33:             <SELECT NAME=cYear>
34:             <%  int startYear = 2000;
35:                 int endYear = 2010;
36:                 for(int y=startYear; y<endYear; y++) {    %>
37:                     <OPTION><%=y%></OPTION>
38:             <%  }   %>
39:             </SELECT></TD>
40:     </TR>
41: </TABLE>
42:     <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE=Submit>
43: </FORM>
44: <HR>
45: <B>Form Content</B><BR>
46: <TABLE>
47: <%  Enumeration parameters = request.getParameterNames();
48:     while(parameters.hasMoreElements()){
49:         String parameterName = (String)parameters.nextElement();
50:         String parameterValue = request.getParameter(parameterName); %>
51:         <TR>
52:             <TD><%=parameterName%></TD>
53:             <TD><%=parameterValue%></TD>
54:         </TR>
55: <%  }   %>
56: </BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not draw any link does it.